# XA error: XAResource.XAER_RMFAIL start() failed on resource Resource manager is unavailable

Tags: oracle11g, weblogic11g, xa

I developed an application on Weblogic 11g and configured a data source to connect Oracle 11g.

When I start the application, I got an error, anyone have the ideas?

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: XA error: XAResource.XAER_RMFAIL start() failed on resource 'My_DataSource': XAER_RMFAIL : Resource manager is unavailableoracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1099)
            at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:238)
            at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.VendorXAResource.start(VendorXAResource.java:50)
            at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.start(DataSource.java:722)
            at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.start(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1228)
            at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.xaStart(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1161)
            at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.enlist(XAServerResourceInfo.java:282)
            at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:507)
            at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:434)
            at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1592)
```

Comment: and how is the data source defined?

Answer (score 4):

One possible cause:
http://www.javamonamour.org/2012/12/xaerrmfail-resource-manager-is.html

"This might well be because your Oracle DB has hit the maximum number of processes. "

For me, restarting WebLogic (along with deleting cache, tmp files of the domain) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your driver is up-to-date. Also, sometimes the XA driver creates problems, hence only use the XA driver if it is really required, for example if you are using a clustered Database.